# Pytest-mock to mock and spy multiple functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

```py
import pytest

def test_example(mocker):
    foo = YourFooClass() 

    spy = mocker.spy(foo, 'bar')
    spy2 = mocker.spy(foo, 'bar2')

    spy.assert_called_once()
    spy2.assert_called_once()
```

I am writing tests for some of my classes and I see that this is one of the ways to assert if a call has been made to a function.

The problem I have is that for some of the tests, the number of spies are increasing to more that 3-4, and I was wondering if this is how everyone writes test cases or whether I am doing something wrong?
I also tried writing them this way

```py
def test_validate_data():
    with patch.object(YourFooClass, '__init__', return_value=None), \
         patch.object(YourFooClass, 'check_columns', return_value=None):
        
        my_class_instance = YourFooClass()

        my_class_instance.validate_data()
```

but this made it more unreadable. (or maybe that is a personal opinion)

What can I do to improve my test case readability and improve not making `spy1,spy2,spy3` and so on?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your test, assuming that you actually do something there what you want to test (instead of just instantiating the class). You could make the tests one-liners (`mocker.spy(foo, 'bar').assert_call_once()`), or if you don't like the syntax, write your fixture that encapsulates this, to write something like `my_fixture.check_called_once(foo, `bar`)`.